# The command exited with Code 1 while building/running

Tags: c#, visual-studio, less

I've continuously been getting this error below when trying to rebuild or run my solution. I've tried doing my own research and none of it's been helpful.

There are no extra spaces in any of the folders and the paths are all correct. The project references all appear to be good as well. I've also tried bumping up the debug to diagnostics, and that doesn't help me much.

```
The command ""C:\Users\username\Desktop\Project\Project\Project.Web\tools\node\lessc.cmd" "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Project\Project\Project.Web\Content\site\site.less" > "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Project\Project\Project.Web\Content\site\site.css"" exited with code 1.   Project.Web
```

This is the line it's failing on

```
<Exec Command="&quot;$(ProjectDir)tools\node\lessc.cmd&quot; &quot;$(ProjectDir)Content\site\site.less&quot; &gt; &quot;$(ProjectDir)Content\site\site.css&quot;" />
```

Any ideas as to what causes this?

Comment: you'll have to look at the output of `lessc`

Comment: Does it really have two leading double-quotes?

Comment: @kmort one is from the error reporter, the other is from the command - although it's not necessary in the example since there aren't any spaces in the paths / filenames.

Comment: Btw. do not put `>` there (it works this way in a trivial case, but potentially leads to a lot of tricky problems here and there. E.g. this is what prevents you to see the actual error message in cases like above). The proper `lessc` usage is `lessc src dst`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after hours of trying to figure it out, i managed to see the problem within 5 minutes of posting this question.

The issue boiled down to me trying to import a file that didn't exist. I removed that @import and it fixed all issues I was having.